# Upgrading Asp.Net Web API from RC1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

We are in process of building a new WebApi. We started out with using .Net Core Rc1 before summer holidays - and now, with .Net Core being 1.0 I would like to update.

But I run into some issues - which I can't figure out if I can solve?

The challenge is that I need to reference some .Net 4.5.1 x86 assemblies.

This means I need to use a moniker that allows use of .Net 4.5.1 - and if I need both worlds, as I understand it - only netstandard16 is available. (https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

But then I run into the issue that .Net 4.6.3 (or vNext in the above link) is not available yet.

If I reference netstandard15 - then AspNetCore libraries won't work.

If I reference netstandard16 - then I get the following errors

```
error : Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
error : 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
error : 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
error : 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.
```

Is it at all possible with current available bits to do the following

- Have a business layer in .Net 4.5 compiled for x86 (need to reuse this - legacy is great)
- Create a Asp.Net Core site
- Reference the business Layer in site - and just carry on coding

Is anyone able to help me out here?

**EDIT: The project.json (in two versions)**

**From RC1**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "BaseClasses": "1.0.0-*",
        "DatabaseAccessCS": "1.0.0-*",
        "BusinessLogic": "1.0.0-*",
        "StandardFunctionsCS": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

**The attempt on final 1.0 that came closest to working**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta902",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta902"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard16": {
      "dependencies": {
        "BaseClasses": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "DatabaseAccessCS": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "BusinessLogic": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "StandardFunctionsCS": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Final json that works**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "platform": "x86"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win":  ["win7-x86", "win8-x86", "win10-x86"]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "LogiholdBusinessObjects": "5.5.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta902",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta902"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your project.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a .NET Core appliction, you should use the `netcoreapp1.0` target framework. You probably won't be able to reference the .NET 4.5.1 library in the .NET Core app.

You could also target a desktop (full) .NET Framework like this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { }
}
```

Now you can use .NET 4.5.1 library but your application won't run on the .NET Core runtime anymore.

You could also target a higher version of .NET, just like `net461 for example.

Comment: But.. If I target net451 i can't use the Microsoft.AspNetCore assemblies right?

Comment: In RC1 I could use both worlds together and it worked fine.

Comment: You can, ASP.NET MVC Core still targets both full .NET and .NET Core.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that yesterday - and had some troubles - but for now, it actually seems to resolve, and compile. 
I will test it out a bit, and convert the remaining code and get back to hopefully close the thread.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck with the references. The "old" assemblies build to a common folder in a parent folder to the csproj file - somehow I am missing something as the project reference fails to resolve this path, but keeps looking in e.g. MyCode\BaseClasses\bin\debug\BaseClasses.dll instead of MyCode\bin\debug\BaseClasses. 
Will return once I figure that out.

Comment: Hi - now I managed to get all the bits working - and got data out of the API. 
Thank you very much for your help - and for confirming the right direction. 
I have some issue with appsettings.json not being copied to output dir, and had to create a nuget package with my x86 assemblies to be able to find them.
But that are obstacles that can be delt with - now that I am sure I have the real foundation in place. 
Had some troubles with running in x86 from Visual Studio - but installing the x86 .Net Core sdk helped on that